# Add a new column to Dataframe and set MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to add a new column `app_vendor_id` and set it as MultIndex with `currency` but I receive an error.

My code :

```
currency = np.array(['BTC','ETH','BCH'])
u = np.array([5000,10000,1046])
cl_bal = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(u, len(created_at)), index= 
pd.MultiIndex.from_product([currency, created_at], names= 
['currency', 'created_at']), dtype= int)
cl_bal = cl_bal.pivot_table(index='currency', columns= 'created_at')
cl_bal.columns = cl_bal.columns.droplevel(0)
cl_bal['app_vendor_id'] = 3
cl_bal.set_index(['app_vendor_id', 'currency'])
```

The error :

> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py",
>   line 3078, in get_loc
>       return self._engine.get_loc(key)
>         File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>          File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>         File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1492, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>          File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>       KeyError: 'currency'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "histo_var.py", line 202,
>   in  cl_bal.set_index(['app_vendor_id', 'currency'])    File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame
>
> line 3909, in set_index
>       level = frame[col]._values
>         File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py",
>   line 2688, in **getitem**
>       return self._getitem_column(key)
>         File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py",
>   line 2695, in _getitem_column
>       return self._get_item_cache(key)
>         File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py",
>   line 2489, in _get_item_cache
>       values = self._data.get(item)
>         File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py",
>   line 4115, in get
>       loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
>         File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py",
>   line 3080, in get_loc
>       return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
>         File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>         File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
>         File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1492, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>       pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
>       KeyError: 'currency'

Comment: you can't set `currency` as index, I think it's already an index so it's not available anymore, you could use `reset_index` before doing so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parameter `append=True` in [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), because `currency` is already in `index`:

```
created_at = [1,2,3,4]
currency = np.array(['BTC','ETH','BCH'])
u = np.array([5000,10000,1046])
cl_bal = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(u, len(created_at)), 
                      index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([currency, created_at], 
                                                       names= ['currency', 'created_at']), 
                                                       dtype= int)
cl_bal = cl_bal.pivot_table(index='currency', columns= 'created_at')
cl_bal.columns = cl_bal.columns.droplevel(0)
cl_bal['app_vendor_id'] = 3
df = cl_bal.set_index(['app_vendor_id'], append=True)
print (df)
created_at                  1      2      3      4
currency app_vendor_id                            
BCH      3               1046   1046   1046   1046
BTC      3               5000   5000   5000   5000
ETH      3              10000  10000  10000  10000
```